# subquery returns more than 1 row?

Tags: mysql, sql

subquery returns more than 1 row ? sulution ?

```html
SELECT `t_files`.*, `t_users`.`username`, 
(SELECT CONCAT(b.first_name, " ", b.last_name)
 FROM t_files AS a
 JOIN t_users as b 
          ON b.id = a.user_id 
) as upload_by 
FROM `t_files` 
LEFT JOIN `t_files_permission` 
   ON `t_files_permission`.`id_files` = `t_files`.`file_id` 
LEFT JOIN `t_users` 
   ON `t_users`.`id` = `t_files_permission`.`id_users`
WHERE `t_files`.`company_id` = '1' 
  AND `t_files_permission`.`id_users` = '59' 
  AND `is_deleted` =0
```

Comment: Add DISTINCT in your sub query.

Answer (score 0):

## Add the condition in your sub query like below

SELECT `t_files`.*, `t_users`.`username`, 
(SELECT CONCAT(b.first_name, " ", b.last_name)
    FROM t_files AS a
     JOIN t_users AS b ON b.id = a.user_id

> WHERE a.id_users` = '59'

) as upload_by 
FROM `t_files` 
LEFT JOIN `t_files_permission` ON `t_files_permission`.`id_files` = `t_files`.`file_id` 
LEFT JOIN `t_users` ON `t_users`.`id` = `t_files_permission`.`id_users`
WHERE `t_files`.`company_id` = '1' AND `t_files_permission`.`id_users` = '59' AND `is_deleted` =0

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
SELECT `t_files`.*, `t_users`.`username`, 
(select CONCAT(b.first_name, " ", b.last_name)
    from t_files as a
     join t_users as b on b.id = a.user_id 
     where t.files.id=a.id) as upload_by 
FROM `t_files` as 
LEFT JOIN `t_files_permission` ON `t_files_permission`.`id_files` = `t_files`.`file_id` 
LEFT JOIN `t_users` ON `t_users`.`id` = `t_files_permission`.`id_users`
WHERE `t_files`.`company_id` = '1' AND `t_files_permission`.`id_users` = '59' AND `is_deleted` =0
```

I think you don't need sub query. You can use join to resolve stuff.