# Subquery returns more than 1 row when aggregation is used

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Subquery returns more than 1 row??

```
SELECT
    `employee`.`employee_id` AS `employee_id`,
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(company.company_profit_left)
    FROM
        company
    GROUP BY
        company.employee_id,
        company.employee_department
) AS profit_left
FROM
    employee
LEFT JOIN `company` ON `company`.`employee_id` = `employee`.`employee_id`
GROUP BY
    `employee`.`employee_id`
HAVING
    SUM(
        company.company_profit_left
    ) = 0
```

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦
║ id ║ user_id      ║ profit left║ department ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬
║  1 ║ 1            ║  100       ║    1       ║ 
║  2 ║ 2            ║   50       ║    1       ║ 
║  3 ║ 1            ║   30       ║    2       ║ 
║  4 ║ 2            ║   20       ║    1       ║
║  5 ║ 2            ║   20       ║    3       ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩
```

and the below table is what I want to achieve

```
╦══════════════╦══════════════╦
║ user_id      ║ profit left  ║ 
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬
║ 1            ║    100       ║  
║ 1            ║    30        ║  
║ 2            ║     70       ║  
║ 2            ║     20       ║  
╚══════════════╩══════════════╩
```

that's why I thought I needed to use group by to distinguish user_id

I have already looked at

[Subquery returns more than 1 row - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750348/subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-mysql)

[subquery returns more than 1 row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342453/subquery-returns-more-than-1-row)

but still don't understand.

By joining two different tables, I get the below table.

anyone can help me solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Based on table structure and output required, I updated the query and removed unwanted `where` and `left join`.

I don't know what you're trying to do. But based on my understanding I corrected your query:

```
SELECT
    employee.employee_id AS employee_id,
    profit_left.employee_department
    profit_left.company_profit
FROM
employee
JOIN (
    SELECT
        company.employee_id,
        company.employee_department,
        SUM(company.company_profit_left) as company_profit
    FROM company
    GROUP BY company.employee_id,company.employee_department
) AS profit_left on employee.employee_id=profit_left.employee_id
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I added tables for better understanding. do you think I can still use group_by?

Comment: Looks like your requirement was pretty straight forward. You don't need `where` or `having` clause and `left join`. I updated my query. You need to show `employee_department` in the output because that's how your profit is divided i.e employee and department.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a correlated subquery.  I'm not sure what you are really doing, but this should fix your error:

```
(SELECT SUM(company.company_profit_left)
 FROM company c
 WHERE c.employee_id = e.employee_id
) AS profit_left
```

You might want this by department instead.  But the point is that aggregation is not appropriate for the subquery.  A correlation clause is appropriate.

Comment: sorry for making you confused. I drew the table for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query grouping all the employee in company tabel and not one of them.you must put where condition in sub query to filter records and no need to grouping in sub query.

Comment: thank you for your idea. I added tables for helping you understand. in that case, do I still need to put where condition?